# Ignore nginx server error_page config for for one specific location directive

Tags: nginx

I have static error pages set up for my server, but I want to ignore those for urls starting with `/api/` so the handler there can respond with a non-200 code, but not return the static error page.

Here is the existing config:

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  example.com;
    root         /var/www/html/;
    index        index.php;

    error_log    /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log   /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_index app.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
    }

    error_page 404 /error/404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /error/50x.html;
    location ^~ /error/ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
    }
}
```

So I think I want to add a new location like:

```
location /api/ {
}
```

But I'm not sure what to use to tell it to *not* follow the server's error_page rule.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, I was struggling with the same thing, but managed to find the (a?) solution.

On the highest level I've got:

```
server {

    include /etc/nginx/boilerplate/fancyerror_and_intercept.conf;


    location ~ (?<target>.*) {
        proxy_pass http://$backend;
    }

}
```

`/etc/nginx/boilerplate/fancyerror_and_intercept.conf` contains:

```
error_page 404 /40x.html;
error_page 403 /40x.html;
error_page 405 /40x.html;
error_page 500 /50x.html;
error_page 501 /50x.html;
error_page 502 /50x.html;
error_page 503 /50x.html;


location = /40x.html {
    root /etc/nginx/error_pages;
}
location = /50x.html {
    root /etc/nginx/error_pages;
}


more_set_headers -s '404 403 405 500 501 502 503 504' 'X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow';
proxy_intercept_errors on;
```

In order to exclude the `/api/` route (Location starts with `/api/` and can contain anything after), add the following:

```
location ~ ^/api/ {
    error_page 527 error.html;
    proxy_intercept_errors off;
    proxy_pass http://$backend;
}
```

In essence the `/api/` location is a duplicate of the general location, but with error_page redefined and intercept errors set to off.

This works, because as [Tim stated earlier](https://serverfault.com/a/836905/383748), the `error_page` directive resets any predefined error_pages. I've chosen error code `527`, because we don't use CloudFlare [see Wikipedia, List of HTTP status codes#Cloudflare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#Cloudflare). Because we `proxy_pass` our requests, you mileage may vary and you might have to change the `proxy_intercept_errors off;` to `fastcgi_intercept_errors off;`.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) says

> These directives are inherited from the previous level if and only if
>   there are no error_page directives defined on the current level.

That suggests you just have to define an error_page for one code that you're not interested in and the rest should reset. This [forum posts](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,223329,223331#msg-223331) supports that.

```
location /api {
  error_page 499 error.html
}
```

Try it out, report back what you find.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, unfortunately it looks like it is still following the default 500 error config and showing my custom 50x.html page. Interestingly, it seems like it totally ignores the error_page directive inside a location block because I used a different 404 rule pointing to a different static file and it still showed the default 404 page (`error/404.html`).

Comment: Furthermore, if I move the server default `error_page` rule into the `/` location block, that rule is completely ignored for any path, and falls back to displaying the symfony error page. That is actually what I want to happen, but *only* for `/api` routes.

Comment: @BenBurleson Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the exact same problem. Show nice & neat error pages when applicable, but for the API, just let the code be in control of what shows.

Comment: exactly. _All_ inherited `error_page` directives from the previous level are overridden by a _single_ `error_page` directive on the current level regardless the status codes in use. The code for the overriding dummy rule need to be valid and in range 300-599. Some codes have a special meaning and cannot be used with `error_page` at all, like the 499 given in the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
location /api {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /path/to/api/handler;
}
```

This way nginx will first check for real files existing under `/api` directory, and if no match is found, then it passes processing to the handler you want to use.

Comment: Thanks, but this is really more for handling 50x errors, not just 404s. Even the `/api` route is processed through `index.php`. All I need is for requests that match this location to *not* follow the server default `error_page` rule.