# How can I turn off fastcgi_intercept_errors for a specific path

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

I just created an API for my flashy new website and was hoping to return error responses with relevant status codes. However, I already configured normal paths to use error pages with the `error_page` directive which I would prefer not removing.

I have one index.php file that handles all requests for the API and website.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name ~^(.+)\.flashy\.local$;
    root "/home/vagrant/flashy/core/www";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    error_page 400 /error/error-400.html;
    error_page 403 /error/error-403.html;
    error_page 404 /error/error-404.html;
    error_page 500 501 /error/error-500.html;
    error_page 502 503 504 /error/error-503.html;

    location ~ ^/error/error-(403|404|500|503)\.html$ {
       internal;
       root /home/vagrant/flashy;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

         fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
         fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
         fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
         fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
         fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
         fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
     }

     location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
     }

     access_log off;
     error_log  /var/log/nginx/~^(.+)\.flashy\.local$-error.log error;

     sendfile off;

     client_max_body_size 100m;

     location ~ /\.ht {
         deny all;
     }

     ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/~^(.+)\.flashy\.local$.crt;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/~^(.+)\.flashy\.local$.key;


}
```

Now, some of you might be wondering? What have I tried?

I tried adding a `/api/` location to change the `fastcgi_intercept_errors` parameter to off, but it seems to get set back to on as it's going to hit a php file anyways.

```
location /api/ {
     fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

I also tried an if statement to see if maybe I could match this based on content headers. However I don't want to use if statements if possible as it seems to be a bad idea.

```
     ...
     fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
     fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
     if ($content_type != "application/json") {
          fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
     }
}
...
```

My question is pretty similar to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/836899/ignore-nginx-server-error-page-config-for-for-one-specific-location-directive) question but it does not have an answer either. Hopefully my questions is slightly different and perhaps better explained?

**How can I turn off fastcgi_intercept_errors for specific api path?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to duplicate the FastCGI configuration within a new `location` for the URI of the API. Most of the `fastcgi` directives can be moved into the `server` block and will be inherited by the `location ~ \.php$` block and the new `location` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html) for details.

An exact match `location` block has highest precedence, so the order of the blocks in this example is not important (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details):

```
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;

fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
fastcgi_read_timeout 300;

location = /api/api.php {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
}
```

The `fastcgi_split_path_info` and `fastcgi_index` directives are not relevant to your configuration.

Comment: The key to a manageable Nginx configuration is a lot of organized include files.  There's no way to avoid duplication.

Comment: Something like this could work but I would prefer a solution that could do this without using two separate php files. I want to keep trying a bit more but perhaps this really is the best solution.